# Google Authentication Error for Google Sheet C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

In my asp.net application, I connected Google Sheets to read some data and show it in my view.

So I logged on to the Google account that Google Sheets has and went to the Google Cloud Console.
There I Enabled API.
Then Generated the API key.
Then I created a OAuth 2.0 Client ID for Desktop Client and got the Client ID and Secret ID.

These are my controller code

```
 public ActionResult getStaffMembers()
{
    string googleClientID = "442784366007-24luel.apps.googleusercontent.com";// This is a sample
    string googleClientSecret = "GhZEwo6Gsl6iE5iqaj1R"; // This is a sample
    string[] scopes = new[] { Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };

    UserCredential credential = Login(googleClientID, googleClientSecret, scopes);
    GoogleSheetManager manager = new GoogleSheetManager(credential);
}

private static UserCredential Login(string googleClientID,string googleClientSecret, string[] scopes)
{
  ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets();
   {
     secrets.ClientId = googleClientID;
     secrets.ClientSecret = googleClientSecret;
    };
   return GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, scopes ,user:"User",CancellationToken.None).Result;
}
```

So the issue is when I run this on Visual Studio, the authentication popup comes from Google and I can pass it and get the data.

But when I publish this application and run it on my IIS server, authentication is not coming and data does not show.

I tried to get the error from the controller to the console and got this error

```
Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile' is denied
```

Need to know a way of fixing this.

Comment: On a IIS you have very little access to the system resources such as the file system.  The connection defaults to GUEST privilege.  I would use a Network drive for storage where users have access.  IIS is very well protected to prevent hackers access.  I would not change access on IIS to allow any user access.  This is not an authentication issue since the connection is completing and code is running.  The issue is the permission of the route.

Comment: @jdweng Now what I tried is I went to this folder ``C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile`` and grant permision for **IIS_IUSERS** and then I tried. Now the error is fixed and now in the console, it showing **Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/rize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.cets" for authorization** and when that link clicked, It asks my Email Address (Google Authentication) but when I filled it and allow the application, then This site can’t be reached msg comes. Could you explain the method is correct I used?

Comment: Most likely the IIS for email ports are forwarding to an email server on the IIS and not your google email server.

Comment: @jdweng Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: You can't fix if the port number is being forwarded to the wrong email server.  You can use the email server on the IIS to send email if you have an account.  The IIS may have a relay that will allow you to send email without an account.https://sendgrid.com/blog/smtp-relay-service-basics/

Comment: @jdweng here in the application, no email is sent to the users. It just opens the Google authentication view and checks the access. Will this related to the above solution ?

Comment: It is not email , but is using the email address and password for authentication.  Relay does not apply.  I think office 365 authentication is being used : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/managing-office-365-endpoints?view=o365-worldwide